# Convert list of strings to list of json objects in pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
def tranform_doc(docs):
    json_list = []
    print(docs)
    for doc in docs:
        json_doc = {}
        json_doc["customKey"] = doc
        json_list.append(json_doc)
    return json_list


df.groupBy("colA") \
            .agg(custom_udf(collect_list(col("colB"))).alias("customCol"))

First Hurdle:
Input: ["str1","str2","str3"]

Output: [{"customKey":"str1"},{"customKey":"str2"},{"customKey":"str3"}]

Second Hurdle:
columns in agg collect_list are changing dynamically. So, how to adjust schema dynamically.
```

when elements in list changes, receiving an error
Input row doesn't have expected number of values required by the schema. 1 fields are required while 3 values are provided

***What I did:***

```
def tranform_doc(agg_docs):
    return json_list
## When I failed to get a list of JSON I tried just return the original list of strings to the list of json


schema = StructType([{StructField("col1",StringType()),StructField("col2",StringType()),StructField("col3",StringType())}])

custom_udf = udf(tranform_doc,schema)

df.groupBy("colA") \
            .agg(custom_udf(collect_list(col("colB"))).alias("customCol"))
```

Output I got:
{"col2":"str1","col1":"str2","col3":"str3"}

Struggling to get the required list of JSON strings and to make it dynamical to number of elements in the list

Comment: Thanks @mck for the quick response. My Spark version is 2.4.5

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Yes @mck. I need the same Key to every element.

Comment: Input: ["str1","str2","str3"] &

Output: [{"customKey":"str1"},{"customKey":"str2"},{"customKey":"str3"}]. 

I need to convert the agg(collect_list()) output to list of JSON objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No UDF needed. You can convert `colB` to a `struct` before `collect_list`.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.groupBy('colA').agg(
    F.to_json(
        F.collect_list(
            F.struct(F.col('colB').alias('customKey'))
        )
    ).alias('output')
)
```

Comment: Thank you @mck.
In the output, we are receiving escape characters. [{\"customKey\":\"str1\"},{\"customKey\":\"str2\"},{\"customKey\":\"str3\"}]. Any Insights to remove them?

Comment: I don't understand why escape characters appear. Do they appear when you do `df2.show(truncate=False)`?

Comment: They appeared while writing to a file. df2.write.mode("overwrite").format('json').save('outFile)

Comment: You can remove `to_json` from my answer, if you're going to write as a json output.

Comment: You made my day @mck. I have struggled a lot to create this from yesterday. It is working perfectly now